# Given a blockhash, how can I prove a transaction with a given hash has been mined?

Tags: solidity, transactions, merkle-patricia-tries

I'm working on a proof-of-relay contract that pays out if and only if a given transaction hash has been mined. I imagine there is some kind of merkle proof that would make this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From within the contract you are limited to a number of predefined [structures](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html#special-variables-and-functions) available to the block containing the contract (see [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7116/can-contract-code-query-the-block-chain) question).

You cannot make granular queries on transactions and their fields. There is a nice code summary of pyethapp [here](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp/wiki/Code-Walkthrough#adding-the-block-to-the-chain) that shows what happens when a transaction is confirmed.

**Edit:**

You'll find all variables that you have access to in solidity [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2664/is-it-possible-to-get-the-transaction-hash-from-within-a-solidity-function-call). The visibility scope is only the last block (which contains the mined contract) meaning that you can't get data on previous and future blocks. That said you can still have a look at the transaction origin; if it is from an account that you expect to make a transaction and appears in the block chain in a non-local node (relative to the initiator of the transaction) then there is a chance that the transaction is going to be confirmed by multiple miners (it's a valid transaction).

Comment: The blockhash contains a hash of the transaction root. Meaning you should be able to pass some combination of header fields and transaction hashes to prove the existence of a given transaction hash

Comment: You don't have access to those header fields from within the contract. At most you can define a contract that accepts a set of fields that have been obtained from the block chain itself and perform some operation over them .

Comment: yup thats exactly what im looking to create. the contract would take inputs and verify a transaction has been mined

Comment: I've edited the answer..